# Buscar resultados a uma API em php/json

Tags: php, json, web-service

Estou a usar a seguinte API: http://api.elsevier.com/documentation/SCIDIRSearchAPI.wadl
Trata-se de uma base de dados de livros/documentos e preciso de aceder lá para ir buscar alguns registos. Já tenho o registo e uma key para usar. 
O que se passa é que nunca fiz nada do género, e não estou a perceber o funcionamento disto. Tenho que fazer uma ligação ao webservice, certo? A partir daí como ir buscar estes dados?

Eles tem um exemplo aqui:
http://apihtmlgen.elasticbeanstalk.com/sd_search.html
. Para já era algo deste género que quero fazer.

Comment: dá uma olhada neste site http://themekraft.com/getting-json-data-with-php-curl/ e neste http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url creio que vai achar o que queres. Já fiz isso com outras API, e o que melhor me atendeu foi a resposta do link do SO.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu pude ver aqui, esta requisição manda um ajax para o site http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/ aonde você pode colocar os parâmetros, por exemplo, a minha query de teste foi "oi":

> http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/index:SCIDIR?query=oi&apiKey=4bc47d36effffe230fdb766b4e90a380&xml-decode=true&httpAccept=application%2Fxml

Este foi o link que foi gerado por ele, o que você precisa fazer é realizar um post ou um get através de um cURL ou ajax veja aqui:

- [jQuery Ajax Post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
- [jQuery ajax Get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
- [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Neste caso o que você precisa fazer é recuperar o que é retornado, que é um xml, através de uma string. Depois você pode usar os métodos do PHP como o [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.simplexml.php) para [ler o xml retornado](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php) e trabalhar com ele.

Se for json é mais fácil ainda, basta usar `json.decode($retorno,TRUE);` para transformar o retorno que você pode pegar através de [cURL](http://codular.com/curl-with-php):

- http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817401/php-send-curl-request-and-wait-for-the-response
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319477/php-sending-post-request-via-curl

Neste caso você não precisa usar javascript, isso torna as coisas um pouco mais simples.